# Why does the transfomation law for contravariant tensors sometimes give me the wrong transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

In my course on symmetry and relativity we have been told that contravariant vectors transform like
$$\bar{x}^{i} = \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{i}}{\partial x^j}x^j$$
I've also been told that the transformation is not necessarily linear and $\bar{x}(x)$ can be any function which has a nonzero jacobian. So say I choose $\bar{x}^i = (x^i)^3$, which obeys the jacobian condition and is a bijection. Clearly the transformation law fails here:
$$\bar{x}^i = \delta^{i}_{j}3(x^j)^2x^j = 3(x^i)^3 $$
Which is not the transformation that was prescribed. This is just one example, it seems like it fails for every nonlinear transformation (and it only works for linear ones because taking partial derivatives is basically the same as taking inner products of the old and new basis, and so the jacobian matrix is just a regular transformation matrix).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. When you contract indices, no index can be upstairs more than once in a product, so e.g. $x^ix^ix^i$ is no good. You could write $\overline{x}^i=c^i{}_{klm}x^kx^lx^m$, with the coefficients obvious from context.

Comment: Also, are you sure the law shouldn't be $\color{blue}{\operatorname{d}}\overline{x}^i=\frac{\partial\overline{x}^i}{\partial  x^j}\color{blue}{\operatorname{d}}x^j$?

Comment: You have a misunderstanding. Vector components are what transform as you wrote. The coordinate functions, however, are in general not vector components.

Comment: @J.G. Ah yes sorry about that, about the transformation law, having them be differential would make a lot of sense but that's not what my lecture notes say

Comment: @Gold That makes sense, thank you. I think I was just confused because my notes say "a coordinate transform is a set of N functions $\bar{x}^i = \bar{x}^{i} (x^{i})$" and so I thought the coordinate functions were always contravariant vector components. Thanks :)